# Compute value from values in row

Tags: r, apply

I have a dataframe x with the columns a & b. I want to have a new column c whichs value is a/b. I've been using

```
x = read.csv(<file>,header=TRUE)
f <- function(...){
x$c = x$a / x$b
}
x = apply(x,1,f)
```

This messes up the dataframe so I suppose this is totally wrong. How can I access the values of the row on which apply is called at a given moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `apply`. These operations work perfectly fine on vectors.

```
x$c <- x$a / x$b
```

Will work just fine on it's own.

For more info check out `?'/'`.

Comment: OP could also use `transform(x, c = a / b)`.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde that's a good alternative, so I guess you could put that as another answer.